# Check if it is biginteger

Tags: java, input, biginteger

i want to create a while loop to check if user's input is biginteger and not an alpha string

```
public class Main{
    private BigInteger a;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = sc.nextBigInteger();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you see if you look in the `Scanner` API documentation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *glancing* at the API documentation answers the question.

Comment: where is while loop ??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigInteger(int)

Comment: i want to set a while loop to make to user insert every time a biginteger and not an alpga string like "apple" 
while(a.isNotBigInteger){
   read again from System.in
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question... but how about

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextBigInteger()) {
  a = sc.nextBigInteger();
}
```

Is this what you are asking? If not, let me know and I'll try to edit it accordingly to your response/comment